# Awesomium: Include external javascript

Tags: javascript, html, awesomium

I'm trying to use functions from external javascript files which are included in my html page with the "script" tag.
Javascript functions which are implemented directly in the html page seem to work without problems but the functions from the external javascript files aren't executed.
Is there a way to get these functions working?

Comment: Can you show how you are referencing your javascript files? And do you know if they exist in the directory being referenced?

Comment: Can you download the JS in an HTTP request in the background and then include it in a script tag?

Comment: The javascript files are embedded in the standard way like "<script src="/somescript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>". They definitly exist in the directory I'm referencing to. The solution to load them in the background and inject the script is a solution I already had in mind but I'm not sure if I like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an external resource as for example a JavaScript file you need to intercept the call using a ResourceInterceptor and inject your file into the response.